# Replacing the first vowel-consonent occurence with consonent-vowel using sub in R

Tags: regex, r

I know that it should be something like this but definitely I am missing something in the syntax:

```
yy=sub(r'\b[aeiou][^aeiou]*',r'\b[^aeiou][aeiou]*',"abmmmm")
```

I expect to have "bammmm" as output

```
Error: unexpected string constant in "yy=sub(r'\b[aeiou][^aeiou]*'"
```

I am not sure how is the exact syntax.

Please run your code in RStudio or any R compiler. I am new to regex and you giving me Python code wouldn't help me to understand the situation. Thanks!

Comment: You can't have the replacement string as a `regex` type.

Comment: Can you explain a bit further? I am new to regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you want

```
yy=sub("\\b([aeiou])([^aeiuos])","\\2\\1","abmm")
```

I'll explain how it works:

- If you ask me to substitute any vowel-consonent with any consonent-vowel? It doesn't make much sense. Should I change ab to ba, ce, or da? It can be any one of them. You never specified any relationship between the vowel in vowel-consonent and the vowel in consonent-vowel. Therefore, it doesn't make sense to put a regular expression in the 2nd argument. As a result, you are not allowed to.
- If you want to achieve what you asked for. You can add brackets to the regular expression in the 1st argument. The first `(` marks group 1, second `(` marks group 2, etc. (note, group 0 is the whole matched string.) You can use \1, \2, ... in the second argument to put the matched group there.

Comment: `Error: unexpected string constant in "yy=sub(r'\b([aeiou])([^aeiou])'"`

Comment: I meant replace it with its reverse. Sounds like I took it granted. You are correct. I thought if I show it like that it will replace it with its reverese. So how can I replace say abmmmm with bammm or acbed to cabde ?

Comment: Plus did you run your code? It gives me error in RStudio! `yy=sub(r'\b([aeiou])([^aeiou])',r'\2\1',"abmmmm")
Error: unexpected string constant in "yy=sub(r'\b([aeiou])([^aeiou])'"`

Comment: `yy=sub(r'\b([aeiou])([^aeiou])',r'\2\1',"abmmmm abm")` gives me `'bammmm bam'` on Python 2.7. See my second bullet point for how it worked.

Comment: Did you see that it's an R question? It has an R tag!!

Comment: I am telling you that I am receiving an error in RStudio! Your code has problem in R and my question is in R

Comment: Actually, regex syntax is not the same everywhere.  Perl is different.

Comment: I have changed it to R syntax.

Comment: @RichardScriven I used nothing out of ordinary in this regex. It works whether you add "perl=TRUE" to this expression or not.

Comment: When I ran your code it didn't replace b and a to bamm `> rep=sub("\\b([aeiou](^aeiou))","\\2\\1","abmm")
> rep
[1] "abmm"`

Comment: `> rep=sub("\\b([aeiou](^aeious))","\\2\\1","abmm")
> rep
[1] "abmm"`

Comment: R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)`> yy=sub("\\b([aeiou])([^aeiou])","\\2\\1","abmm")
> yy
[1] "bamm"`

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to using a regular expression for this, there's a nice string reversal function in `example(strsplit)`

```
> strReverse <- function(x)
      sapply(lapply(strsplit(x, NULL), rev), paste, collapse="")
> dd <- "abmmmm"
> paste(strReverse(substr(dd, 1, 2)), substr(dd, 3, nchar(dd)), sep = "")
[1] "bammmm"
```